# ToolTip for FileUploadField Ext.NET control

Tags: asp.net, ext.net

How could I add a tooltip to a `ext:FileUploadField` control? I tried to assign a ToolTip for my Browse button like the below, but it's not working.

```
<ext:FileUploadField ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" Icon="BrowsePicture" ButtonText="" ButtonOnly="true" AutoPostBack="true">
    <ToolTips>
        <ext:ToolTip runat="server" ID="FileUpload1_TT" Title="Browse" Html="Browse"></ext:ToolTip>
    </ToolTips>
    <Listeners>
        <FileSelected Fn="showFile" />
    </Listeners>
</ext:FileUploadField>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set `Target="#{FileUpload1}-file"` on the `<extTooltip>`.

The following example demonstrates the full scenario.

**Example**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="Ext.Net" Namespace="Ext.Net" TagPrefix="ext" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Ext.NET Example</title>
</head>
<body>
    <ext:ResourceManager runat="server" />

    <form runat="server">
        <ext:FileUploadField ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" ButtonOnly="true" ButtonText="Select">
            <ToolTips>
                <ext:ToolTip runat="server" Title="Browse" Html="Browse" Target="FileUpload1-file" />
            </ToolTips>
        </ext:FileUploadField>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Wrapping the string `FileUpload1` with `#{}` will ensure the client-side .ID (.ClientID) is used to reference the correct instance of the `<ext:FieldUploadField>` object.

Hope this helps.